# Another Fine Myth

Tags: riddle, wordplay

A mysterious quartet of haiku, taken together they describe a single figure.

> When my life began
>   inside the superlative
>   city of angels
>
> When the seed was placed
>   by a son of the entombed
>   a swine most untamed
>
> With my brothers' help
>   in the centre protected
>   I formed a new land
>
> My marriage a curse
>   among polite company
>   she's actually great

Hint:

> The myth in question is not Greco-Roman, and the choice of Haiku should not be considered a clue, it is purely stylistic.

Hint 2:

> The third haiku is likely to provide the biggest clue as to which Mythology we're in.

A fifth Haiku was found, this just grows mysteriouser and mysteriouser.

> From your home to mine
>   there's a rainbow connection
>   where the rhyme doubles

Comment: from history or more recent times?

Comment: @WeShall I'm not sure what you're asking, exactly, so I'll just state that the word Myth in the title should not be construed as misleading. The rest of the title, however, was blatantly stolen from Robert Asprin's fine book of the same name.

Comment: That was to get an idea on women from what era should I Google :)

Comment: Is this describing a real person, or a mythological figure?

Comment: If it's not greco-roman, what other myths exist?

Comment: @Sid Is that a real question? There's a whole bunch of different types. Egyptian is pretty widely-known and was the focus of Stargate, Marvel has been using Norse in comic books for ages, and I beleive Celtic mythology influences the show Merlin. Elements of Shinto are present in several Anime, and I believe most people have been exposed to at least pieces of both Abrahamic and Hindu mythologies.

Comment: @Sconibulus I thought Greco-Roman were the mythologies that maximum people were exposed to. Hindu mythologies or Shinto Mythologies are not that well known I think.

Comment: @Sconibulus, very interesting. So, is that _all_ the mythologies _you're_ knowledgeable on? Jk.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are lots of bits I can't make work, but the fourth and fifth haiku seem to point strongly to

> Odin, from Norse mythology.

My marriage a curse
among polite company
she's actually great

> Odin's wife is called Frigg, which sounds like a slightly-rude word in English (and one which is sometimes used as a partially-minced version of a much ruder word). The last line might reflect (1) the fact that Frigg is an important and powerful goddess or (2) the fact that her name means something like "beloved".

From your home to mine
there's a rainbow connection
where the rhyme doubles

> A rainbow connection between (it seems) two worlds? That sounds an awful lot like Bifröst, whose first two letters are suggestive of doubling. (The *rhyme*? Well, Robert *Frost* was a poet.)

I'm having enough trouble fitting any of the first three haiku to this that I suspect it's wrong, but maybe I'm missing some important things. Still, let me say what little I can about them. Credit to Angzuril for most of this (some bits I'd thought of but not clearly enough, and rejected).

When my life began
inside the superlative
city of angels

> Presumably this is Asgard, though an *aes* isn't exactly an angel and a *gard* isn't exactly a city.

When the seed was placed
by a son of the entombed
a swine most untamed

> Angzuril suggests awfully plausibly that this is a reference to Borr (which sounds kinda like "boar"), whose father entered the world by being liberated from a block of ice.

With my brothers' help
in the centre protected
I formed a new land

> I suppose this must be Midgard, (mid=centre, gard=guard=protected) but "gard" doesn't really mean protected and even "guard" dooesn't (it means "protect" or "protector"). Was Midgard formed by Odin and his brothers? I am far from an expert on this stuff, but everything I've seen so far suggests that the main thing Odin and his brothers did together was to fight one another. ... Oh, but now that I look up Borr I see that the Voluspa says that Midgard was created by "his sons", so fair enough.

(After that I'm a bit more convinced than I was before.)

Comment: I think your answer is correct, and just beat my own

Comment: I can't see what else it could be. But those first three stanzas all seem like stretches to me.

Comment: Rhymes, by Frost as well as doubled rime(frost); The first stanza was intended to reference his mother. The man encased in ice, who fathered Borr was named Buri, by the way. So it also sort of worked two ways.

Comment: Best-LA. Oh my word. (And I completely missed rhyme=rime.) Incidentally, anyone inclined to upvote my answer here should go and upvote Angzuril's as well, or instead.

Comment: My, my.  I spent a bunch of time thinking about "be-LA-st" or "besLAt".  Should've just Googled BestLA!

Answer (score 5):

My Answer:

> Odin

When my life began
inside the superlative
city of angels

> Least sure about this,but likely refers to Asgard

When the seed was placed
by a son of the entombed
a swine most untamed

> Odin's father is Bor (swine) and his father was uncovered from ice for his birth

With my brothers' help
In the centre protected
I formed a new land

> Odin and his brothers created Midgard (which is at the center of Norse mythology)

My marriage a curse
Among polite company
She's actually great

> Odin's wife is typically Frigg, which sounds like what some people would say instead of a more common F expletive.

From your home to mine
there's a rainbow connection
where the rhyme doubles

> The connection between Asgard (home of the Aesir (Gods)) and Midgard is the Bifrost, a rainbow bridge.

Answer (score 4):

I believe we may be speaking about:

> [Rama](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rama) and more generally Vishnu.

When my life began
inside the superlative
city of angels

> Bangkok, or "กรุงเทพมหานคร อมรรัตนโกสินทร์ มหินทรายุธยามหาดิลก ภพนพรัตน์ ราชธานีบุรีรมย์ อุดมราชนิเวศน์ มหาสถาน อมรพิมาน อวตารสถิต สักกะทัตติยะ วิษณุกรรมประสิทธิ์". [From here](https://www.into-asia.com/bangkok/introduction/fullname.php): "In the official English romanisation, this is certified as the longest place name in the world in the Guinness book of records. It's pronounced something like: Krung Thep Mahanakhon Amon Rattanakosin Mahinthara Ayuthaya Mahadilok Phop Noppharat Ratchathani Burirom Udomratchaniwet Mahasathan Amon Piman Awatan Sathit Sakkathattiya Witsanukam Prasit"

And means:

> The city of angels, the great city, the residence of the Emerald **Buddha**, the impregnable city (of Ayutthaya) of God Indra, the grand capital of the world endowed with nine precious gems, the happy city, abounding in an enormous Royal Palace that resembles the heavenly abode where reigns the reincarnated god, a city given by Indra and built by Vishnukarn.

When the seed was placed
by a son of the entombed
a swine most untamed

> Mohini (seed), Varaha (boar)

With my brothers' help
in the centre protected
I formed a new land

> His brother in his incarnation as Rama was Lakshmana

My marriage a curse
among polite company
she's actually great

> "His wife Sita is considered by Hindus to be an avatar of Lakshmi and the embodiment of a great woman."

If I'm on the right track, I believe there's a considerable amount left to do. I am still looking through most of it.

Comment: A good guess, but this doesn't fit the haiku particularly well.

Answer (score 3):

Tentative answer:

> Hades/Pluto

When my life began
inside the superlative
city of angels

> 'city of angels' if we stretch it a little, could be olympus, land of the gods. Hades doesn't actually live there though, see stanza 3.

When the seed was placed
by a son of the entombed
a swine most untamed

> ?????? this stanza stumps me. Entombed kind of fits though.

With my brothers' help
In the centre protected
I formed a new land

> Perhaps the underworld is the 'centre' of the earth? That would be his new land.

My marriage a curse
Among polite company
She's actually great

> I mostly guessed this because this last stanza reminds me a lot of Persephone and how she is 'cursed' to spend half her year in the underworld with Hades, although compared to most greek gods, they're marriage is very stable and healthy.

Comment: Not a terrible guess, but not what I was going for. Note the wordplay tag

Answer (score 1):

Quartet 2

When the seed was placed by a son of the entombed, a swine most untamed

> **Heracles**
>  son of a mortal - *Alcmene* and related to a untamed swine - *Erymanthian Boar*

Quartet 3

With my brothers' help in the center protected I formed a new land

> **Zeus**
>  created the island of - *Delos* with the help from his brother - *Poseidon*

Quartet 4

My marriage a curse among polite company. She's actually great

> **Leto**
>  Was cursed for accidentally catching the eyes of Zeus and was banned from giving birth on land or sea. Actually she is mother of -  *Apollo and Artemis*

Not able to get a good context for the Quartet 1 but based on the above 3 people, I guess you are...

> **Hera**
>  Wife of - *Zeus*
>  One who cursed - *Leto*
>  And step mother of - *Heracles*

Comment: You've got one of the clues partially right, but mostly you're well off-base

Comment: @Sconibulus, will start over. I would not have read about the above characters in detail if not for this riddle. The journey is the reward. Thanks.